# Why <a> tag doesn't navigate properly to url if using www.something.com

Tags: html

I was working on  tag and let say my domain was `www.abc.com`. If I use `href="http://example.com"` it does properly navigate to intended url. However if I use `href="www.example.com"` it doesn't navigate to intended url.

```
<a href="www.google.com">not properly navigate</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">properly navigate</a>
<a href="http://google.com">properly navigate</a>
```

I was reading the anchor specs in https://html.spec.whatwg.org, unfortunately could not find this specific case.

Comment: What happens when you use "www.example.com"? Does it not navigate at all or does it go to some other url?

Comment: @PriyankPanchal Let's asume the page is hosted under `http://www.example.com/testing.html` The first link would result in a request to the page `http://www.example.com/www.google.com`

Answer (score 5):

The browser must know if you want to link to another website or a different file/page of your own website. The browser always asumes that you want to link to a file on your own server if you do not specifiy the protocol.

In fact: The only reason you can leave the protocol out when typing a url into the addressbar of your browser is because the browser just asumes that you want to use the `http`-protocol. This is not possbile with urls inside the A tag.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is it browser dependent or all browsers behave the same?

Comment: it is browser dependent, but today every browser (at least all that I know) do this.

Comment: I just test on chrome and firefox for this, and it will not properly navigate with `href='www.example.com'`

Comment: @Haziq did you read my answer properly? You can only omit the protocol when you type the address manual in the addressbar. Using the `a`-tag the protocol is **mandatory**. It navigates properly, just not to your intended location, becasuse you gave a incomplete address.

Comment: My previous comment was reply to @PriyankPanchal. Yes i did read your comments and really appriciated

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify an absolute url it will think it's a route inside your site.

#### Possible values using `href` attributes:

- An absolute URL - points to another web site (like href="http://www.example.com/default.htm")
- A relative URL - points to a file within a web site (like href="default.htm")
- Link to an element with a specified id within the page (like href="#top")
- Other protocols (like https://, ftp://, mailto:, file:, etc..)
- A script (like href="javascript:alert('Hello');")

Comment: a script is also just another "protocol"

Comment: so browser will think that `www.google.com` is not an absolute URL?

Comment: @Haziq exactly. i.e if you try to run your code in `jsfiddle` and click the link you will get `https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/www.google.com` - like it's trying to find a route with that name inside jsfiddle website.

Answer (score 0):

Because When you click on it.. Your Browser Will suppose he need to find this link in the same file extension.
Example: if your html file extension is e://tst.html
when click on tag at Browser it will go to e:// and search about file with name "www.google.com" and not find it..
Use `<a href="http://www.google.com">not properly navigate</a>` to inform Browser you need to navigate to Another website